# I started a project with laravel, vuejs, inertia js and jetstream. but I have a problem with my form I can't get all the data

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, laravel-jetstream

I started a project with laravel, vuejs, inertia js and jetstream. but I have a problem with my form I can't get all the data from the form, here is the code of my component invoice.vue.

```
<script setup>

import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue';

import {  ref} from 'vue';
import { reactive } from 'vue';
import {Inertia } from "@inertiajs/inertia";


const showLine = ref([false])

let item = ref([])
let listCart = ref([])

const addCart = (item) => {
    const itemCart = {
        id: item.id,
        unite: item.unite,
        pu: item.pu,
        designation: item.designation,
        qte : item.qte
}

        listCart.value.push(itemCart)
}

const removeItem = (i) => {
    listCart.value.splice(i,1)
}





const Total = () => {
    let total = 0
 listCart.value.map((data) => {
        total = total + ((data.qte)* (data.put) );
    })
    return total
}

let content =  Total();

 let itemCart = reactive({


       unite:'',
        pu:'',
        designation:'',
        qte:''

});

let form = reactive({
grand_total: content ,
reference: '',
intitule: '',
name: '',
date: '',
address: '',
destinataire: '',
terms_and_conditions: '',

});





let submit = () => {

    Inertia.post('invoice', form);
    
};


</script>


<template>
    <AppLayout title="Invoice   ">






<main class="flex-1 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto bg-gray-200">
    <div class="container sm:mx-96    px-0 py-12">

        <h3 class="text-3xl font-medium text-gray-700">
   Nouvelle facture
    </h3>
      <div class="mt-4">


    </div>


                    <div class="mt-8"></div>

    <div class="flex flex-col-3 mt-2 ">
        <div class="py-2 -my-2 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 sm:px-6 lg:-mx-8 lg:px-8">

                    <div class="inline-block min-w-full overflow-hidden align-middle border-b border-gray-200 shadow sm:rounded-lg">

                            <form @submit.prevent="submit">

                        <table class="min-w-full ">

                        <tbody class="bg-white">
                                <tr>
                                        <td class="px-4 py-4 border-b border-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap">
                                                <div class="flex items-center">


                                                                <div class="ml-4">
                                                                    <div class="text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-900" >

                                                                                    <input type="text" v-model="form.name" name="nomEntreprise" placeholder="Nom de l'entreprise">
                                                                    </div>


                                                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class=" border-b border-gray-200">
                                                <div class="flex items-center">


                                                                <div class="ml-4">
                                                                    <div class="text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-900" >

                                                                                    <input type="text" v-model="form.address" name="adressEntreprise" placeholder="Adresse de l'entreprise">
                                                                    </div>


                                                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class=" border-b border-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap">
                                                <div class="flex items-center">


                                                                <div class="ml-4">
                                                                    <div class="text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-900" >

                                                                                    <input type="text" name="reference" v-model="form.reference" placeholder="Numéro facture">
                                                                    </div>


                                                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                                        </td>

                                </tr>



                                <tr>
                                        <td class="px-4 py-4 border-b border-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap">
                                                <div class="flex items-center">


                                                                <div class="ml-4">
                                                                    <div class="text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-900" >

                                                                                    <input type="Date" name="Date" v-model="form.date" placeholder="Date délivrance">
                                                                    </div>


                                                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                                        </td>

                                        <td class=" border-b border-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap">
                                                <div class="flex items-center">


                                                                <div class="ml-4">
                                                                    <div class=" text-gray-900" >

                                                                                    <!-- <input type="text" name="Intitule" placeholder="Intitulé de la facture"> -->
                                                                    <textarea name="intitule" id="" v-model="form.intitule" cols="30" placeholder="Intitulé de la facture"></textarea>

                                                                    </div>


                                                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class=" border-b border-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap">
                                                <div class="flex items-center">


                                                                <div class="ml-4">
                                                                    <div class=" text-gray-900" >

                                                                                    <!-- <input type="text" name="Intitule" placeholder="Intitulé de la facture"> -->
                                                                    <textarea name="destinataire" id="" v-model="form.destinataire" cols="30" placeholder="Destinataire"></textarea>

                                                                    </div>


                                                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                                        </td>



                                </tr>

                        </tbody>



                        </table>

                            <div class="mt-8"></div>


                        <table class="table-auto">
                                    <thead class="border-gray-200">
                                        <tr>
                                        <th class="px-1 py-3 text-xl font-medium leading-4 tracking-wider text-left text-gray-500 uppercase border-b border-gray-200 bg-gray-50">Désignation</th>
                                        <th class="px-1 py-3 text-xl font-medium leading-4 tracking-wider text-left text-gray-500 uppercase border-b border-gray-200 bg-gray-50">Unité</th>
                                        <th class="px-1 py-3 text-xl font-medium leading-4 tracking-wider text-left text-gray-500 uppercase border-b border-gray-200 bg-gray-50">Qte</th>
                                        <th class="px-1 py-3 text-xl font-medium leading-4 tracking-wider text-left text-gray-500 uppercase border-b border-gray-200 bg-gray-50">PU</th>
                                        <th class="px-1 py-3 text-xl font-medium leading-4 tracking-wider text-left text-gray-500 uppercase border-b border-gray-200 bg-gray-50">prix total (FCFA)</th>
                                        <th class="px-1 py-3 text-xs font-medium leading-4 tracking-wider text-left text-gray-500 uppercase border-b border-gray-200 bg-gray-50"></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>

                                                        <tr  v-for="(itemCart) in listCart" :key="itemCart.id">
                                                        <td class="px-1 py-4 border-b border-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap"><textarea name="designation" v-model="itemCart.designation" placeholder="Désignation" id="" cols="20" ></textarea></td>
                                                        <td class="px-1 py-4 border-b border-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap"><input type="text" name="unite" v-model="itemCart.unite" placeholder="unité" ></td>
                                                        <td class="px-1 py-4 border-b border-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap"><input type="number"  v-model="itemCart.qte" name="qte" placeholder="Qté" ></td>
                                                        <td class="px-1 py-4 border-b border-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap"><input type="number" v-model=" itemCart.pu" name="pu" placeholder="PU" ></td>
                                                        <td class="px-1 py-4 border-b text-zinc-600 font-bold border-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap"><p v-if="itemCart.qte" > {{(itemCart.qte)*(itemCart.pu)}}</p> </td>
                                                        <td class="px-1 py-4 text-xl border-b text-red-600 font-bold border-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap"><a type="button" @click="removeItem(i)"> &times;</a> </td>
                                                        </tr>

                                                        <tr>


                                                            <td class="border-b border-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap"><textarea v-model="form.terms_and_conditions" name="terms_conditions" id="" cols="20" placeholder="Termes et conditions" rows="5" ></textarea></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>

                                                            <td><p></p></td>
                                                            <td><p></p></td>
                                                            <td><p></p></td>
                                                            <td class="border-b border-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap"><p >Total HT</p></td>
                                                            <td><p>(FCFA)</p></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><p></p></td>
                                                            <td><p></p></td>
                                                            <td><p></p></td>
                                                            <td class="border-b border-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap"><p>Total </p></td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <p id="totalElements" > {{ Total() }} (FCFA)</p>

                                                                </td>
                                                                <input type="button" v-model="grand_total">
                                                        </tr>


                                                    </tbody>

</table>


<div class="mt-8"></div>

     <a type="button" class="px-96 py-2  mx-24 rounded sm:inline-block bg-blue-700 font-semibold text-white " @click="addCart(item)">
    Ajouter une ligne  <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>

     </a>
<div class="mt-8"></div>

     <button class="px-24 py-2  mx-96   rounded sm:inline-block bg-blue-700 font-semibold text-white"

       type="submit"
      >
    Enregistrer

     </button>

    </form>
                    </div>
       </div>




     </div>

    </div>
</main>






</AppLayout>
</template>
```

I would like to get all the data from my form but I don't know how I can do to get the data from the fields ( v-model = itemcart.description, v-model = itemcart.pu, v-model = itemcart.qte ). I tried but I can't do it.

and this is what I tried to do:

```
let form = reactive({
    listCart:[
        itemCart.designation,
        itemCart.pu,
        itemCart.qte,
        itemCart.unite,
    ],
grand_total: content ,
reference: '',
intitule: '',
name: '',
date: '',
address: '',
destinataire: '',
terms_and_conditions: '',

});
```